# Generating a datetime range

Tags: arrays, datetime, google-bigquery

I'd like to generate an array of datetime timestamps with incrementing steps of 1 hour

Example:

```
[2018-01-01 10:00:00, 2018-01-01 11:00:00, 2018-01-01 12:00:00]
```

The array function`GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` does what I want, but unfortunately it appears to work only for day/week/month, and not intra-day time granularity

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GENERATE_ARRAY` function with the `ARRAY` and `TIMESTAMP_ADD` functions to build an array with the desired range. Here is an example:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2018-01-01 10:00:00', INTERVAL x HOUR)
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, TIMESTAMP_DIFF('2018-01-01 12:00:00', '2018-01-01 10:00:00', HOUR))) AS x
  ) AS timestamps
```

If you want to, you can make a SQL UDF and then call that instead:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MakeRange(lower TIMESTAMP, upper TIMESTAMP) AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(lower, INTERVAL x HOUR)
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(upper, lower, HOUR))) AS x
  )
);
SELECT MakeRange('2018-01-01 10:00:00', '2018-01-01 12:00:00') AS timestamps
```

Comment: You see. Elliott is way smarter than me. I still prefer my UDF though ;-)

Comment: @GrahamPolley I have an advantage because I specced and implemented `GENERATE_ARRAY` and `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` ;) For future reference, [this is the feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71693426) to have e.g. `GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY`.

Comment: I can't compete with that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone much smarter than me will find a way to do this is SQL (*narrows eyes at Mikhail*), but how about using a JavaScript UDF.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  generate_stepped_timestamp_array(step FLOAT64,
    iterations FLOAT64)
  RETURNS ARRAY<TIMESTAMP>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  var timestamps = [];
  var start = new Date('2018-01-01');
  for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
    start.setHours(start.getHours() + step);
    timestamps.push(new Date(start));
  }
  return timestamps;
  """;
SELECT
  generate_stepped_timestamp_array(1,
    24) AS stepped_array
```

[image]

Clearly, I'm no JavaScript gun! There's probably a much nicer/better way of doing implementing this in JS. But, hopefully you get the idea nevertheless.

I found did find [this](http://www.pittfagan.com/blog/2017/10/22/generating-timestamps-using-the-generate_date_array-function-in-bigquery/) on my travels. As a side note, I think a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%20status:open) for something like `GENERATE_DATETIME_ARRAY` or similar would be well received.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we're unable to use UDF's as they have much stricter rate limit quotas. Thanks for the link, I'll try and see if I can use that